# Modelling (long-ish) APIs in Typescript declaration files

Tags: javascript, typescript, definition, typescript-typings

I am a bit confused about how you are supposed to model APIs in Typescript.

I am trying to model the [hexo](https://hexo.io/api/tag.html) API, which for example usage, looks a bit like this:

```
hexo.extend.tag.register(name, function(args, content){
  // ...
}, options);
```

So far I have got something which looks like this:

```
//hexo.d.ts
declare module 'hexo' {
    namespace extend {
        export class tag {
            public register: _register;
        }
    }
}

declare class _register {
    name: string;
    callback(args: any, content: any); 
    options: _options;
}

declare class _options {
    ends: boolean;
}
```

However, I am getting issues like:

> Property 'register' does not exist on type 'typeof tag'.

So how should I model this, it seems as though Typescript becomes a bit tricky after you have declared a class in a namespace in a module, and none of those types can exist within themselves?

What would `a.b.c.d.e.f()` look like in a `.d.ts` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, something is only a class if it is called with `new`. Otherwise it is
just a plain object. I'd do something like that:

```
declare module 'hexo' {
    class Hexo {
        constructor( cwd, opts )
        load() : Promise<any>
        extend : {
            console : any //declare me later, set any for now 
            // etc
            tag : {
                register(name:string, cb: (args,content) => void , opts : any)
            }
        }
    }
    export = Hexo;
}
```

`export = something` is used when the module exports a single object (class Hexo becomes the module itself, not an object inside it).

PS: callback types (and actually any type) can be referenced using the `type` keyword. The `type` keyword may even replace the `interface` keyword...

```
type someCallback = ( err : Error , resp : HttpResponse ) => Promise<any>
```